# root@localhost permission denied

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, ssh, root, localhost

I installed `ssh` in my Ubuntu 14.04. I followed a tutorial for generating `ssh` keys. I used following commands to set the keys.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" 
cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

when I type `ssh` on the localhost as a normal user it will not ask for any passwords and it works fine but when do it as a root it is asking for root@localhost password and my root password is not working.

Here is what I have tried so far by visiting some stack-overflow.com and AskUbuntu questions regarding this error.

- Everyone suggested to create a password by `sudo su` then `passwd`. I tried it. I created a password and it's not working. I tried it several times.
- I tried `ssh-add` as root but it says `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent`
- I tried generating the keys as root by doing `ssh-keygen -t rsa -P`  then`cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`. After doing this when I start `ssh localhost` it is asking for root@localhost password and it is not accepting my root password.
- I tried changing `PermitRootLogin` to yes and `withoutpassword`. Neither worked.
- I added a new property to the `sshd_config` saying AllowUsers root. It also did not work.

*I would really appreciate some help.*

Answer (score 1):

The way you added authorised keys, you haven't added your user's key to root's authorised keys. You have added your own key to your authorised keys and root's key to root's authorised keys. Instead do:

```
sudo tee -a /root/.ssh/authorized_keys  < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```